# Change selected div from query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, query-string

I have the following dropdown based on bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form_name">Title</label>
  <select id="hpsel" class="c-form-profession form-control">
    <option value="con01">Option 1</option>
    <option value="con02">Option 2</option>
    <option value="con03">Option 3</option>
    <option value="con04">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want to change selected value from query string so `?something=con02` opens the page with con02 pre-selected.

I tried a few ways from other answers but they don't seem to work on my bootstrap dropdown.

Comment: can you post what you tried ? or links to those answers and how they failed to do what you want?

Comment: Tried this mainly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181403/set-option-selected-if-url-query-string-matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const something = urlParams.get('something');

document.getElementById('hpsel').value = something;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('something');

document.querySelector('option[value=' + myParam + ']').setAttribute('selected', "")
```

Comment: Bonus tip: you can let the browser select the matching `<option>` automagically, if you set the `value` of the `<select>` element to a value that matches any of the `<option>` elements' value.