# How to redirect to another page and select option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got 8 anchor links on my homepage. How to make them directly redirect to page 2 and select the right option differs to link.

1st Page:

```
<a href="page2">1</a>
<a href="page2">2</a>
<a href="page2">3</a>
<a href="page2">4</a>
<a href="page2">5</a>
<a href="page2">6</a>
<a href="page2">7</a>
<a href="page2">8</a>
```

2nd Page:

```
      <div class="formSelector">
        <label for="type">Choose one</label>
        <select id="formSelector">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
          <option value="Option-1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="Option-2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="Option-3">Option 3</option>
          <option value="Option-4">Option 4</option>
          <option value="Option-5">Option 5</option>
          <option value="Option-6">Option 6</option>
          <option value="Option-7">Option 7</option>
          <option value="Option-8">Option 8</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

I am new at this so I didn't tried anything. Just searched direct solve and couldn't find anything related to my question.

Comment: Have a look at the following article at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location basically you relocate and then send a hash (your value from the selection) to the new page, then have the code on the new page retrieve the hash value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set option 'selected' if url query string matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181403/set-option-selected-if-url-query-string-matches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your URLs to include a [search parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search) `option`, then use [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) and the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to get that search parameter from the second page. You can then use the parameter passed through the URL to select the proper option.

Here's an example of how you can do that:

*page1.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-1">1</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-2">2</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-3">3</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-4">4</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-5">5</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-6">6</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-7">7</a>
    <a href="page2.html?option=Option-8">8</a>
</body>
</html>
```

*page2.html*

```html
<div class="formSelector">
    <label for="type">Choose one</label>
    <select id="formSelector">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="Option-1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option-2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option-3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="Option-4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="Option-5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="Option-6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="Option-7">Option 7</option>
        <option value="Option-8">Option 8</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    const formSelector = document.getElementById('formSelector');
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    formSelector.value = url.searchParams.get('option');
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
        formSelector. dispatchEvent(new Event('change')));
</script>
```

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77011583/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-and-select-option/77011795#comment135762102_77011583) suggested doing this with a URL hash. That will work fine too, however I personally prefer to use URL parameters because URL hashes are also sometimes used to jump to sections on your page.

Comment: It worked very well but another problem occured, I use another [script for hide elements](https://hastebin.skyra.pw/udoterajet.js) of the page, when you choose an option a form appears related to the option. With your code this function is now not working. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @Preflyt Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer and it should work now. The problem was that setting `<select>`'s value from JS doesn't fire a `change` event, so you need to [manually fire](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) the `change` event yourself with `formSelector.dispatchEvent()` and the `Event` constructor (its easier than it sounds, and a good thing to keep in the back of your head if an event isn't firing).